# Does Ubuntu support Bluetooth 3.0?

Tags: 11.10, sound, pulseaudio, bluetooth, thinkpad

I am running 11.10 on my Thinkpad E420, and it has integrated Bluetooth 3.0, yet when I use my Plantronics Backbeat 903+ (which uses Bluetooth 2.1) I get terribly inconsistent audio with many complete dropouts.

I also have a USB Bluetooth 2.1 dongle, and when I attach that and use it instead of my internal adapter I get perfect audio quality.  This is why I am curious as to whether or not Ubuntu has Bluetooth 3.0 support.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I also have issues with my a2dp audio using integrated bluetooth 3.0 adapter. My laptop - Samsung RF511. Bluetooth:
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0a5c:219c Broadcom Corp. What's your BT chip?

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK Ubuntu does support Bluetooth 3, and even if it did not, your Bluetooth 3 capable adapter is using Bluetooth 2.1 for Bluetooth 2.1 devices. Quite likely it is just a driver issue, or your internal adapter might simply do poorly with that device because of how it is built (for example if it does not use enough power for the transmission or what ever. It may even be that it is not getting a clear enough reception).

Comment: Well, I don't think it is a reception issue because I have had these issues when I've been across the room from my laptop and when I've been sitting right in front of it.  Driver issues seem to be the most apparent feasible issue.  Any suggestions as to how I might resolve these possible issues with the driver?

Comment: @Dannation it depends on the availability of a better Linux driver for your hardware, but that is unlikely. Most bluetooth adapters will work just fine in Linux, so that is why I am guessing it is a hardware related problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% related, but I have also noticed extremely short range connectivity & dropouts with this Plantronics Backbeat headset when using it with an Android 2.3 phone... if this is a Linux driver issue it may not be specific to Ubuntu (or even traditional Linux platforms)... but it could equally be a hardware compatibility issue between these bluetooth chips.  Have you been able to verify if this problem is also present with Windows?... this may help to determine if the problem is in software or hardware.

Comment: I do not think the Backbeats have issues with Windows.  Since I originally posted this I have bought a different kind of Bluetooth headphones and sold my Backbeats to my little brother who runs Windows on his Lenovo IdeaPad with my old 2.1 dongle.  He seems to be having no issues, but he's using the same dongle that I was using when I was having no issues as well.  I have bought a pair of Noikia BH-905i, and these work perfectly, so I don't really know what the problem could be with the Backbeats.